# Querying custom LDAP filtering with last created 24 hours

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I want to use LDAP query to return all user objects created in the last 24 hours with the following Attributes.

I have like below so far.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))
```

Attributes:

```
samaccountname (username)
givenName (first name)
sn (last name)
mail (mail addresses)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You'll need some code to generate a string for "24 hours ago" (or whatever delta time you want). The datetime string format needs to be YYYYMMDDHHmmss.0Z -- the timestamp is UTC.

The following filter finds all Active Directory users created since 11AM UTC yesterday:

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(whenCreated>=20200617110000.0Z))`

If you want to find accounts that have *changed* in the previous time delta, change whenCreated to whenChanged

Comment: worked for me! in my case I've used it in PowerShell as Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(whenCreated>=20220920145500.0Z))'

Answer (score 1):

Here is my powershell answer to the question. Not an LDAP filter, but it will get the info you want.

```
$1DayAgo = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).Date

$UserProperties = "samaccountname", "givenName", "sn", "mail"

Get-ADUser -Filter {whenCreated -ge $1DayAgo} -Properties $UserProperties
```

Comment: FWIW, the `-Filter` argument is translated to LDAP, so in essence it is an LDAP filter :D

Comment: A (possibly more readable) alternative to the first line: 
`$1DayAgo = (Get-Date) - [Timespan]::FromDays(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Compare against `whenCreated`, using the date time format `yyyyMMddHHmmss.fZ`:

```
$since = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime().ToString('yyyyMMddHHmmss.fZ')
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(whenCreated>=$since)"
```

Comment: Hi Mathias how can I do via LDAP search filter ? I need define LDAP config inside application.

Comment: @Arbelac There's no way (that I know of at least) to build a static filter describing "the last 24 hours" - you'll need to populate the filter with an absolute offset every time

Comment: I got it. So how can I filter samaccountname which is beginning with PRD and / or TST prefix and only ENABLED users ?